# laravel laravelLTE installation issue

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

I followed the following instructions:

1. First, I ran:

   ```
   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel laravelLTE
   cd laravelLTE
   php artisan migrate
   ```

   ...which results in the following error:

   > [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
   >   Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found
2. Then, I modified *laravel/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php* and retried `php artisan migrate`, but I see the same error as above.
3. Next, I tried installing the LTE admin template package:

   ```
   composer global require "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel:4.*"
   ```

   ...and then added: `Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider::class` and `'AdminLTE' => Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Facades\AdminLTE::class` to the `'providers'` and `'aliases'` arrays in *config/app.php*.

   After running, `composer update`, I see the same error as above, followed by this error:

   > Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
4. Finally, I ran this command:

   ```
   php artisan vendor:publish --tag=adminlte -force
   ```

   ...which results in this error:

   > [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
   >   Class 'Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider' not found

What am I doing wrong? **I am using Laravel 5.4.36 and PHP 5.6.25**.

Also, I am having a problem setting the domain or URL to e.g. laravel.dev.

Comment: It appears you are not importing namespaces correctly.  Do you really have a `Schema` class in your `App\Providers` folder?

Comment: Tried to help you edit your text to make it clearer, but it's unreadable. I suggest that you rewrite your question and format it in a way that is easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: J Whit, as Marcus, I tried editing your question to make it clearer and improve formatting, but there's still some missing information. The question states that you modified *AppServiceProvider.php*. What changes did you make that are important to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Go to App\Providers and In the AppServiceProvider.php, you did not include the necessary use statement at the top of the file.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

That defines the namespace path to the Schema class so you can simply call

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

in the boot method.